# Remove lines from one document that exists in another document with a batch file on Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file

I would like to remove lines from one document that already exists in another document.

Example:

Document 1

```
A
B
C
D
```

Document 2

```
A
C
```

New Document

```
B
D
```

Is there a way to write this as a batch file on Windows?

This question has been asked here before, but none of them helped me as all of them are for Linux or something else that didn't work in a batch file.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal

rem Define the lines in Document2
for /F "delims=" %%a in (Document2.txt) do set doc2["%%a"]=1

rem Show lines in Document1 that are not in Document2
for /F "delims=" %%a in (Document1.txt) do (
   if not defined doc2["%%a"] (
      set /P "=%%a" < NUL
      echo/
   )
)
```

Previous Batch file *may* fail if a document contain quotes, although this depends on the position of the quotes vs. spaces. It is convenient that Document1 be the largest of the two files.

Answer (score 0):

Windows batch file do not have file read capabilities that can handle this.  It has no replacement for grep or any of the advanced text searching capabilities of Linux, so AFAIK, it can't be done using vanilla Windows batch script.

I won't recommend any custom windows batch scripter because they are all different and if you want to go that route, you can just use the Linux answers on windows by finding the right batch scripting program to install.

If you provide a full context of why you want to do this, maybe there is a better way to do this other than using Windows batch script?  You can easily make self-contained executables using more powerful scripting engines like AutoHotKey and other similar programs.

Comment: What I would like to do is the following:
I have 2 playlist (with songs) and 1 playlist has songs I already used in a mix. The other one contains a list of all my songs. So by removing the songs from the first in the second playlist ( or vice versa) I get a new playlist with songs that I haven't used jet.

Thanks for your quick respond.

Comment: Are the playlist strictly just the list of songs?  I think there will be special symbols and/or tags in there to specify that it is a playlist.  You will remove the essential tags and end up with a broken playlist if you did what you wanted... so it really depends on the playlist's format.  

Can you post a sample?

Comment: This is an exemple (first part) of an playlist:

#VirtualDJ Playlist
#MixType=Smart
K:\0\House\hard\edx-hoover (phunk investigation remix).mp3
K:\0\House\hard\Agent Greg & Terri B! - Time Won't Wait (Inphinity dubmix).mp3

Comment: I can't get the format right, but every song in the playlist is the exact location and full name of the song

Comment: Besides the first couple lines (#VirtualDJ Playlist
#MixType=Smart)

Comment: Well, I can definitely say you can't do this with Windows batch code :)  

You will need to write code to parse the initial file, and then remove records from the other files.  For sure Windows batch file can't handle it.  I would recommend looking into AutoHotKey, but there are definitely other similar solutions available.